# MS Azure VM drive mess

Tags: ubuntu, azure, virtual-machines, cloud, microsoft

I'm new to Azure and I already hate it :D

Anyway, I'm trying to do a simple task - create a VM with 8 cores, >=8GB RAM, 128GB drive (gonna run Ubuntu server on it). Just ONE OS drive. Nothing else.

Now, when I create a VM, it gets assigned a 32GB OS drive and there is no way for me to change that size during the creation process. Can I do that somehow? Did I miss anything?

Do other VM sizes get different OS drive sizes? Where can I find that information?

Also, I've read somewhere that I'd pay according to how much storage space I use:
1) does that apply for the OS drive?
2) does using up all the space on the OS drive increase the total cost or is it just a money-saving feature for the clients?
3) is the OS drive price included in the VM price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an OS disk size at deploy time. You can resize it after deployment (see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk)) and you can add data disks to the VM at deploy time.

You are indeed charged storage costs for the VM disks, including the OS disk. If you are using managed disks (which you should be) then you are charged for the total size of the disk, regardless of whether you use it all. The OS disk cost is not included in the VM price.